# What is the fluid released from the tail of this clipped Turkish airliner?

Tags: aircraft-systems, accidents

A Turkish A321 airliner was [hit](https://youtu.be/ee_FLbODhKc) by an Asiana A330 on 13 May 2018 at Istanbul Airport. It seems a large amount of fluid was released from the damaged section. What is the fluid? There is no APU up there so only hydraulic fluid, am I right?

[image]

Some news: https://onemileatatime.boardingarea.com/2018/05/13/turkish-plane-tail-istanbul/

Comment: That's the plane peeing itself after getting hit by the other plane.

Answer (score 5):

It is hydraulic fluid. This works on 3000psi so that would explain the geyser.

I am not familiar with the A320 family but on most aircraft hydraulic system there are usually isolation valves to ensure that part of the system remains serviceable if there is a sudden loss of pressure/fluid in one part of the system.

Comment: I think you are talking about hydraulic fuses and they are normally on the landing gear to retain pressure for the other brakes if a line blows.  There wouldn't be anything like that on lines going to the rudder system.

Comment: is that really 20 MPa, i.e., 200 atm?

Comment: 3000psi for most aircraft. The A380 works with 5000psi.